# Profiling in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried profiling one of our QT Applications today (using Visual Studio 2015).
Failing initially I did the following:

```
vsperfcmd /admin:driver,start /admin:service,start
vsperfcmd /admin:security,allow,FullAccess,myusername
vsperfcmd /admin:security,allow,FullAccess,mydomainname\myusername
vsperfcmd /admin:driver,autostart,on
```

Which got me beyond the inital error messages. Sadly, everytime it starts the application it crashes and I get the error message:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

Which in good Microsoft tradition does not give any useful information which access to what is denied.

Is there any way to figure out, what the tools are complaining about?

Comment: No I am not. Our company does not give us minions admin rights.

Comment: The above commands were run as Administrator. But not VS.

Comment: It's always a mistake not to give developers admin rights on their own machine.

Answer (score 0):

After adding my user to Administrators, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your IT admins to apply the following procedure on your machine: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182387.aspx

Once that's done you should be able to profile with your non-admin account.